# Jmeter - values from Regular expression extractor is not getting written in the file

Tags: jmeter

I have added a regular expression as below in order to extract the response value inside the xml.

```
p400="http://newman.services.premium.hellocorp.com">(.+?)</p400:newman></soapenv:Body>
```

the reference name is  "output_xml"

I have added a simple data writer as well and added "output_xml" to the sample variables in Jmeter properties file also. Still I am not able to see the xml getting written in the file.

Please advice me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that it's possible with simple file writer, try FlexibleFileWriter plugin http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=FlexibleFileWriter

And have you checked, that this extractor works on your data?

Try to add Debug Postprocessor (ensure that "JMeter variables" is set true)  and View Results Tree elements to you project and inspect variables.

Answer (score 0):

The given xml formats

```
p400="http://newman.services.premium.hellocorp.com">(.+?)</p400:newman></soapenv:Body>
```

You need to update the following regex formats to extract the response values

Regular expression formats

```
http://newman.services.premium.hellocorp.com">(.+)</p
```